# Zombie process is generated when call system() in Perl threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

There have two Linux nodes(hostA and hostB) in my test environments, I need to trigger a script(worker.sh) to run on all nodes concurrently, the worker.sh was already placed in all nodes,  so I use threads module in my Perl scripts(master.pl), here is the code snippet:

```
use threads(stringify);

sub runByThreads{
   my($count,$funcion,$host_ref,$cmd) = @_;
   @hostlist = @{$host_ref};

   my $thread;
   my @failNodes;

   for (my $i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
      my $host =@hostlist[$i];
      $thread = threads->create($funcion,$host,$cmd);
      $parserState{$thread} = $host;
      $thread_num ++;
   }

   while ($thread_num != 0) {      # stuck in this while loop
      foreach my $subthread(threads->list(threads::joinable)) {
         my $ret = $subthread->join();
         if ($ret != 0) {
            ....
         }
         $thread_num --;
     }
     sleep 2;
   }
}

sub runCmd {
    my ($host,$cmd) = @_;

    chomp($localhost = `hostname -f`);
    if ($localhost eq $host) {
        $ret = system("source /etc/profile; $cmd");
    } else {
        $ret = system("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ".$host." \"source /etc/profile; ". $cmd."\"");
    }
    return $ret;
}


main {
    my @servers = qw/hostA hostB/
    my $nodecount = scalar(@servers);
    my $arg = "--node";

    $cmd = "$HOME/worker.sh "."$arg";
    my @ret = &runByThreads($nodecount,\&runCmd,\@servers,$cmd);
    if ( scalar(@ret) != 0) {
        $failNum += 1;
    }
}

&main;
```

This perl script is run on hostA, in normal case, the ps command shows:

```
0 S optitest  9338  9337  0  80   0 - 50630 pipe_w 06:57 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl master.pl
0 S optitest  9992  9338  0  80   0 - 26536 wait   06:57 ?        00:00:00 sh -c source /etc/profile; /home/jack/linux/worker.sh --node
0 S optitest 10023  9338  0  80   0 - 14151 poll_s 06:57 ?        00:00:00 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostB source /etc/profile; /home/jack/linux/worker.sh --node
0 S optitest 10757 10741  0  80   0 -  1608 pipe_w 06:59 ?        00:00:00 grep 9338
```

but sometimes, the ps shows there has a defunct process exists, and the defunct process will cause master.pl stuck in the while loop,

```
0 S optitest  6503  6502  1  80   0 - 50628 pipe_w 05:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl master.pl
0 Z optitest  7496  6503  0  80   0 -     0 exit   05:51 ?        00:00:00 [hostname] <defunct>
0 S optitest  7497  6503  0  80   0 - 26536 wait   05:51 ?        00:00:00 sh -c source /etc/profile; cd /home/jack/linux/worker.sh --node
```

I know zombie process is a process that has completed execution (via the exit system call) but still has an entry in the process table , This occurs for child processes, where the entry is still needed to allow the parent process to read its child's exit status: once the exit status is read via the wait system call, the zombie's entry is removed from the process table and it is said to be "reaped"

I am confused how the defunct process was generated in my tests, the defunct process should be the one run work.pl on hostB via ssh, but I found it seems the process become defunct process immediately when it created by the Perl system call, because I didn't see any output for its run, even the 'echo' in the first line of worker.sh was't executed.

One thing is also strange, in worker.sh, some scripts are called to run in background, If I empty the worker.sh on hostB, the defunct issue can also be happened, but if I empty the worker.sh on both hostA and hostB, I never see the defunct issue again.

Sorry for the long post, I am trying my best to make my question more clear, could you please help me to check what was going wrong, did I miss anything when use the threads module, or there have some issues of the threads module, because I noticed that the use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged. http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html

Comment: Try [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are listed in the perldoc as "discouraged".  Personally, I find they work fine, they're just somewhat counter intuitive - they *aren't* lightweight constructs like might be assumed (based on other threading models).

I will note - the generic solution to self-reaping zombies is to set `$SIG{'CHLD'}` e.g.: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html but that's probably not a good idea if you're capturing the return code. You could probably do an `open` and a `waitpid` instead though.

So I wouldn't normally suggest their use, unless you've a scenario where you need to do a lot of inter-thread communication. `Parallel::ForkManager` is generally much more efficient.

If you do have to use them - I wouldn't do what you're doing, and spawning a thread per 'job' and instead use a worker threads model with `Thread::Queue`.

I can't say for certain, but I suspect one of your problems is this line:

```
$cmd = "$HOME/worker.sh "."$arg";
```

Because perl will be interpolating `$HOME` - and you don't define it, therefore it's null.

You really should be turning on `strict` and `warnings` and cleaning up any errors as a result - your code has quite a few.

But that said - unless I'm missing something your code is much more complicated than it needs to be - it looks like all you're doing here is running parallel ssh commands.

So I'd suggest what you'd be better off with is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my @servers = qw/hostA hostB/;

my $cmd         = '$HOME/worker.sh --node';
my $threadcount = 2;

my $hostq  = Thread::Queue->new();
my $errorq = Thread::Queue->new();

sub worker {
    while ( my $hostname = $hostq->dequeue ) {
        my $output =
            qx( ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $hostname \"source /etc/profile; $cmd\" );
        if ($?) {
            $errorq->enqueue("$hostname: $output");
        }
    }
}


$hostq->enqueue(@servers);
for ( 1 .. $threadcount ) {
    my $thr = threads->create( \&worker );
}
$hostq->end();

foreach my $thr ( threads->list ) {
    $thr->join;
}
$errorq->end();
while ( my $error = $errorq->dequeue ) {
    print "ERROR: $error\n";
}
```

Alternatively, with `Parallel::ForkManager`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @servers = qw/hostA hostB/;

my $cmd     = '$HOME/worker.sh --node';
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);    #fork limit.

foreach my $hostname (@servers) {
    $manager->start and next;
    my $output =
        qx( ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $hostname \"source /etc/profile; $cmd\" );
    if ($?) {
        print "ERROR: $hostname $output\n";
    }
    $manager->finish;
}

$manager->wait_all_children();
```

Comment: Re "Threads are officially discouraged", No, they are not. The warning atop threads.pm is a miswording. It's actually reference to the previous paragraph. Threads are discouraged *if you don't want to deal with the fact that they are heavy*.

Comment: Well, I don't know how much more "officially discouraged" you can get than the perldoc saying: "The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged.". I agree - they work fine if you set them up right.

Comment: I've just said that sentence is incorrectly worded. Officially, threads are not discouraged. Officially, threads are discouraged *if you don't want to deal with the fact that they are heavy*.

Comment: I shall amend the answer.

Comment: @ikegami, this might be more suited for chat, but may I ask why you say the discouragement is unofficial?  The warning from 5.20's threads.pm appears starkly in perldelta-5.20, and survives into 5.22's updated threads.pm.  Moreover all those warnings link to perlpolicy's discouraging explication of what official discouragement means.  That seems rather official to me.

Comment: @pilcrow, Cause p5p said the warning is strictly related to the previous paragraph and not to be taken generally.

Comment: @pilcrow, I can't seem to find some of the replies I remember getting, just the one that says the previous paragraph is the reason for the thread. That same message points to this [discussion](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/perl/porters/305035) that lead to the creation of the patch.

Comment: @pilcrow, I see three points made in that discussion: 1) I've never had to use threads, 2) multi-threading is hard, and 3) "unmanaged expectations of support are causing social problems". /// To that, i say 1) Yet they exist 2) It's multi-tasking that's hard. Using processes instead doesn't help, 3) the comment is causing social problems discouraging legitimate uses of threads. /// Notice that none of the reasons listed are technical except for the heavyness of the threads (solved by using a worker model). It's all politics.

Comment: @Sobrique, thanks for your answer, I have a question about the thread queue in your code, does the code can ensure the threads is joinable when using $thr->join ,  I also applied your code to my script, but found the script was stuck since the thread cannot be joined.

Comment: Join blocks until a thread is joinable.  The threads should exit automatically thanks to ending the queue.

Comment: @Sobrique, the version of Thread:Queue is 2.11 in my machine, no end queue method in this revision, seems I need to do a upgrade.